practicality of an equality
Yesterday I came across this post which briefly states that $$\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$$  after a bit of work I managed to expand this and show that
$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{a_2}{b_2} = \dots = \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\sqrt[k]{a_1^k+a_2^k+ \dots+a_n^k}}{\sqrt[k]{b_1^k+b_2^k+ \dots +b_n^k}}$$
And the proof goes as follows .(if you want to take a look at it)
Let $\frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{a_2}{b_2} = \dots = \frac{a_n}{b_n} =t \implies a_1=tb_1 , a_2=tb_2 \dots a_n=tb_n$
So the sum $$a_1^k+a_2^k+ \dots+a_n^k=t^k(b_1^k+b_2^k+ \dots +b_n^k)$$
therefore  $$t^k=\frac{a_1^k+a_2^k+ \dots+a_n^k}{b_1^k+b_2^k+ \dots +b_n^k} \implies \\t= \frac{\sqrt[k]{a_1^k+a_2^k+ \dots+a_n^k}}{\sqrt[k]{b_1^k+b_2^k+ \dots +b_n^k}} \blacksquare$$
My question is : Are there any practical uses for this ? from what I tried I couldn't find any uses that are not unnecessary.
For example if we have two similar right triangles with proportion of $λ$ then by using this equality we can show that for their corresponding sides let's call them  $AB , KL$  ,$AB= λ \times KL$ . Which is not necessary at all. Any Ideas would be much appreciated!

NIce equality but equally occurs with $t= \dfrac{\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2 \dots a_n}}{\sqrt[n]{b_1b_2 \dots b_n}}$ and this is also a well known property of proportions (I translate the spanish word proporciones  which is maybe bad English I don't know)

What you proved is a basic proportionality law. It's a modified form of addendo.
Thinking about practical usage,
$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=t,t\in N$$
This means that if $a,b,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ form a Pythagorean triplet, $x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ are bound to form a Pythagorean triplet too.
These will also have a variety of applications in linear algebra, like finding out unit vectors along a given direction
